# Error with php code (file upload)

Tags: php

I am getting the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: theimage in C:\wamp\www_upload\index.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: theimage in C:\wamp\www_upload\index.php on line 7

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$target_path = "images/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['theimage']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theimage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "<p>The image ".  basename( $_FILES['theimage']['name']). " has been uploaded</p>";
} else{
echo "<p>There was an error uploading the image, please try again!</p>";
}  

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
</head>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<input name="theimage" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</fieldset>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this please ?

Comment: What does `print_r($_FILES)` give you ?

Comment: Can you post the var_dump or `print_r` of the `$_FILES` array?  Also, what are the values for these three php settings? `file_uploads`, `upload_max_filesize`, `max_file_uploads`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['theimage'])) {
    // YOUR CURRENT PHP CODE HERE
?>
```

The problem is the upload script is executing even if nothing is posted (like when you first load the page).

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you're getting data in `$_FILES` or `$_POST` before you try to do anything with them:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES)) {        // if(isset($_POST)) 
                                // would work as well
        $target_path = "images/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['theimage']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theimage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "<p>The image ".  basename( $_FILES['theimage']['name']). 
                " has been uploaded</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>There was an error uploading the image!</p>";
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit button to:

```
<input type = 'submit' name = 'theSubmitBtn' value = 'Upload'>
```

Then, wrap all of your php code at the top inside of this if check:

```
if(isset($_POST['theSubmitBtn'])) {

... Your Code ...

}
```

See if that works for you.  On a side note, you will also need to add much more error checking if this is to be used in a production environment.